# smtp письма с авторизацией с html содержимым

Tags: email, php, smtp

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// функция отправки, с выводом ошибок
function smtp_mail($user_smtp, $pass_smtp, $to, $subject, $message, $headers = ''){
 $recipients = explode(',', $to);
 $smtp_host = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
 $smtp_port = 465;
 if (!($socket = fsockopen($smtp_host, $smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, 15)))
 echo "Could not connect to smtp host '$smtp_host' ($errno) ($errstr)", __FILE__, __LINE__;
 server_parse($socket, '220');

 fwrite($socket, 'EHLO '.$smtp_host."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '250');

 fwrite($socket, 'AUTH LOGIN'."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '334');

 fwrite($socket, base64_encode($user_smtp)."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '334');

 fwrite($socket, base64_encode($pass_smtp)."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '235');

 fwrite($socket, 'MAIL FROM: <example@gmail.com>'."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '250');

 foreach ($recipients as $email){
 fwrite($socket, 'RCPT TO: <'.$email.'>'."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '250');
 }

 fwrite($socket, 'DATA'."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '354');

 fwrite($socket, 'Subject: '.$subject."\r\n".'To: <'.implode('>, <', $recipients).'>'."\r\n".$headers."\r\n\r\n".$message."\r\n");

 fwrite($socket, '.'."\r\n");
 server_parse($socket, '250');

 fwrite($socket, 'QUIT'."\r\n");
 fclose($socket);
}

// вызываем функцию
if(smtp_mail('email@site.ru', 'pass', 'email2@site.ru', 'head', '<div style="">text</div>')) {echo "Mail sent";}
else {echo "Some error occured";}
```

Функция работает. Передаю ей 5 параметров: Емайл, пароль от него (на кого оформлено мыло, которое раздает письма), внутренний ящик, заголовок, текст письма

У меня текст письма

```
<div style="">text</div>
```

Вот такая конструкция вместе с html тегами и доходит. т.е. как текст. Подскажите, что дописать что бы было html письмо... и буквы были, ну т.к. писать охота не только 'hello world', прошу подсказать как указать кодировку windows-1251 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример Полей:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Comment: Ок. Если не секрет, это вписать в функцию после:

    $smtp_host

?

Answer (score 1):

Взял бы html-письмо и посмотрел как оно устроено) В служебных заголовках твоего письма указан content-type: text/plain, поэтому отображается как текст. Тебе нужно установить в это поле значение text/html

Comment: Да, это так. В той же функции mail() вполне быстро можно найти где прописывать text/html, и кодировку. При смтп отправке не могу найти где и как прописать тот же тип письма и туже кодировку. Уважаемые, никто не подскажет как тип письма прописать?